# Selenium selecting on an icon

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, select

I have to select on a download button in selenium.
The div tag looks like this:

```
    <div onmouseout="_menuItems['14'].LeaveMenuItem()" class="dropDownSubMenu" style="padding: 0mm; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; width: 100px;" id="_div14"><a id="_item12" class="dropDownMenuItemLink" onmouseover="_menuItems['12'].OnMouseOver();" onclick="javascript: _menuItems['12'].DecrementUsage(); _menuItems['12'].OnClick();" href="javascript:;" onmouseout="_menuItems['12'].LeaveMenuItem();" style="display: block; padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px;"><span class="dropDownMenuItemLabel" id="_lbl12" style="">Excel</span></a><a id="_item13" class="dropDownMenuItemLink" onmouseover="_menuItems['13'].OnMouseOver();" onclick="javascript: _menuItems['13'].DecrementUsage(); _menuItems['13'].OnClick();" href="javascript:;" onmouseout="_menuItems['13'].LeaveMenuItem();" style="display: block; padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px;"><span class="dropDownMenuItemLabel" id="_lbl13" style="">CSV</span></a></div>
```

The idea is to click on that download icon which then displays an option "Excel". Select that option and wait for the download.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

I share the table I would like to download and its html code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: tag your binding language

Comment: what do you mean? I am using pyhon

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for xpaths :

click the download using the below xpath :

```
//div[contains(@onmouseout,  '_menuItems[') and contains(@onmouseout, '14') and @class ='dropDownSubMenu']
```

and click on Excel with below xpath  :

```
//div[contains(@onmouseout,  '_menuItems[') and contains(@onmouseout, '14') and @class ='dropDownSubMenu']/descendant::span[text()='Excel']
```

Since you have tagged python :

use it those xpath like this :

```
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@onmouseout,  '_menuItems[') and contains(@onmouseout, '14') and @class ='dropDownSubMenu']"))).click()
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@onmouseout,  '_menuItems[') and contains(@onmouseout, '14') and @class ='dropDownSubMenu']/descendant::span[text()='Excel']"))).click()
```

**Imports** would be :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: it raises me a Timeout Error. As an alternative I might directly download the table on python. But am unable to do so.

Comment: can you share web site URL ?

Comment: I can but it requires a username and a password which II cannot provide you: https://app.evaluate.com/ux/WebReport/tabbedsummarypage.aspx?itemId=1070&lType=modData&compId=1019&tabId=&sceName=

Comment: can you go to dev tool (in chrome press F12) - > elements - > ctrl + F ->  search `//div[contains(@onmouseout,  '_menuItems[') and contains(@onmouseout, '14') and @class ='dropDownSubMenu']` do you see anything getting highlighted ?

Comment: No but when I inspect the word "Excel" the inspector highlights this: `<div onmouseout="_menuItems['6'].LeaveMenuItem()" class="dropDownSubMenu" style="padding: 0mm; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; z-index: 0; width: 100px;" id="_div6">`

Comment: okay the xpath that I have given you `//div[contains(@onmouseout,  '_menuItems[') and contains(@onmouseout, '14') and @class ='dropDownSubMenu']` - contains 14 ,you may want to replace with 6 and see if that works

Comment: thank you @cruisepandey. I actually found out a solution by copy-pasting the xpath by inspector. In any case II will try also your solution!

Comment: The locators looks to be dynamic, I do not think that it will be a reliable selector

Comment: I see...so you think that I won't be able to select on Excel?

Comment: you will be right now.. but probably not to tomorrow or some day,  cause that's not reliable selector

Comment: ok. So also if I put the 6 it doe not work...it raises me the TimeoutError